# How can I use await/async in both a ashx and aspx files on the same site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to run an async task in the code-behind for my aspx page. I am using `Page.RegisterAsyncTask` and `Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks` to run the async method.

However I get the error saying I need to add `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />` to my webconfig file, but in adding that line, my use of async/await start throw an error in my ashx pages.

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.

Async/await work perfectly fine in the ashx page before adding `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />` So how can I have async/await working in both kinds of files?

Comment: For the class associated with your ashx file; what does it inherit from?  
`:HttpTaskAsyncHandler` or `:IHttpAsyncHandler` or `:IHttpHandler` ?

Comment: `IHttpHandler`. The await is inside the processRequest method. It is using an await-able library method. The handler itself is not awaited by anything.

Comment: Replaceing `IHttpHandler` with `HttpTaskAsyncHandler` did the trick

Comment: That's great that it worked for you.  For what it is worth I have written this up as a full answer now.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Nowadays when creating ashx files, you probably want them to be asynchronous by default.  The framework has support for this by using the new `HttpTaskAsyncHandler`.

Just inherit from `HttpTaskAsyncHandler` instead of `IHttpHandler`.

Then delete the method:

```
public ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

and move its code to be inside

```
public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
```

where you can take advantage of Tasks

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution :)

Comment: If an ashx derives from `HttpTaskAsyncHandler`, will legacy clients that call it still work without change?  Or do clients need to then use UploadStringAsync?

Comment: @Terry, Apologies, this is a couple years since you asked :(   Legacy clients will continue to work just the same.  They are requesting the file over HTTP so they have no idea what the internals of the .ashx file are.  Furthermore the client might be a browser or JavaScript or some other **non** .NET client, so UploadStringAsync is certainly not mandatory.